# Finding possible solutions to a modular arithmetic question.

Tags: number-theory

How many solutions does the quadratic equation $\bar{x^{2}}= \bar{2}$ have in $\mathbb{z}_{47}$? 
The only way i can think of doing this is computing all the squares within the modulo. But i know there is a quicker way just don't know what this would be?

Comment: Because the prime $47$ is of the shape $8k\pm 1$ there are two.

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic reciprocity was made to answer exactly this kind of question. In your case you can use the supplements.

Comment: what supplements of quadratic reciprocity? thats what im not sure about?